# How to implement sessions or cookies in Python

Tags: python, cgi, webserver, wsgi

can anyone help me get sessions or cookies working with my code here:
http://pastebin.com/2Y2tydsF

I have tried a few session modules that I found with Google but nothing seems to work, or I dont know how to use it.

I have also fiddled with cookies but with no luck

Also, what are the differences, and what are CGI and WSGI apps? and would my code be one of the two?

Thanks

Comment: Are you stuck on using SimpleHTTPServer?  There are lots of web frameworks that make your app code simpler and give you stuff like sessions for free.  I like CherryPy.

Comment: I don't actuall know how to use cherry py to be honest, I tried a while ago but couldnt fiqure how to use it. Would it work for me? If I sat and read up exactly how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [gai-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki). The source includes demos which show how to use it, including how to integrate with the Users API or RPX/JanRain.

Comment: Isn't gae-sessions (what your link is to) only for GAE apps?  It appears to require a working WSGI setup to integrate with, at least.

Comment: Oh no, does Beaker not work on AppEngine? I may have to bookmark that link.